# How to organize data into separate vhdx disks using Docker (on WSL2)?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I am running Docker on Windows 11 with WSL2 integration enabled. If I create a volume named "my_awesome_volume" in Docker Desktop then the following folder is created:

```
\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes\my_awesome_volume\_data
```

I understand that this data lives in the ext4.vhdx for docker-desktop-data. I don't want to store data for all of my containers here. I'd like to isolate some of my data into separate vhdx disks for portability and organization purposes. So, I created a new my_storage.vhdx for data storage, formatted it as ext4, and mounted it in WSL. This was successful, and I can access/read/write this storage from any distro on my system using the following path from within the distro:

```
/mnt/wsl/my_storage_folder
```

Or from Windows (any distro works but my example uses docker-desktop-data):

```
\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wsl\my_storage_folder
```

I am unable to access this storage using a Docker volume, though.

I understand how to create a volume with access to the host file system, like this:

```
volumes:
      - /c/my_host_folder/config:/config
```

Of course, performance is better if files aren't read from the Windows host, but if I do this:

```
volumes:
      - my_awesome_volume:/config
```

My data is pointed at the docker-desktop-data container.

Is it possible to create a Docker volume (in Windows w/ WSL2) that points to a folder in the my_storage.vhdx I created? How?

I tried to follow a couple of examples using the local driver options, but I couldn't get anything to work.